# Yii - bind onclick event with CLinkPager with each pager link

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii

i want to call a function with each pager link in Yii CLinkPager, i used below code without any luck.

```
'pagerCssClass' => 'pagination',     
'afterAjaxUpdate'=>"FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0)",
'beforeAjaxUpdate'=>"FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0)",
```

i used js method too

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ajaxListView a').each(function(){
            $(this).click(function(ev){

                FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0);

                });
        });
});
```

But above code only works for one time and not works when i click on next or back paging numbers. I used alert("") instead of  FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0); and got the same error.

Plz help me that how i can bind a js function with each click of paging link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `on`.

```
$(document).on('click','.yiiPager a', function(){
    console.log('clicking');
    FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0);        
});
```

Where `yiiPager` is the css class of the list that becomes the pager. 
Also note, that `CLinkPager` doesn't have a `pagerCssClass` property.

Comment: no luck.. it logs only one time, i need to log every time on click the link.

Comment: Yii framework uses jQuery version 1.6 which does not support "on".

Comment: You are incorrect. jQuery 1.7.1 was added in version 1.1.9 (January 2012). http://static.yiiframework.com/files/CHANGELOG-1.1.10.txt